# How to properly format backslashes for MongoDB $text search in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to perform AND $text search in MongoDB. This is how my query looks in mongoDB Compass:

```
'$text': {'$search': '"\"hello\" "\"world\"'}
```

which correctly finds all the entries which have both `hello` and `world`.

Howewer, I have troubles getting this string in Python. If I do

`words = '"\"hello\" "\"world\"'`

in the actual query I get `'""hello" ""world"'`, since backslashes are treated as escape characters and OR $text search is performed. If I do

`words = '"\\"hello\\" "\\"world\\"'`

in the query I get `'"\\"hello\\" "\\"world\\"'` and no entries are found at all. So I get either no backslashes or two.

Am I missing something? What is the proper way for performing AND $text search with Python and PyMongo?

Comment: What happens with `words = '""hello"" ""world""'`, or `words = '"hello" "world"'`?

Comment: It performs OR search

Comment: Sorry I'm taking stabs in the dark here, but I expect I'll need to know the answer to this soon.  What happens with `words = '\"hello\" \"world\"'` or `words = '\\"hello\\" \\"world\\"'`?